# Using expect.any(String) in object comparison in jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a code like below

```
    expect(insertedData).toEqual({
                id: expect.any(String),
                clientId: 'client1',
                ...
```

I expect id should match any string, but what I get as result is

[image]

Not sure what I missed.

Also I used like below still same error

```
expect(insertedData).toEqual(expect.objectContaining({
```

Comment: It is probably because the constructor of the `id` and `lastModifiedDate` fields' values are not `String`. Can you check it?

Comment: They're going to be an ObjectId and a Date, no?

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me. Turns out the problem is not with the fields with expect.any() but the other field. Seems it just bad diff there.

Answer (score -1):

The problem on your expression relies on the first expectation which is

```
toEqual()
```

the expectation should use **toMatchObject** like:

```
expect(insertedData).toMatchObject({...
```

Comment: ```expect(insertedData).objectContaining({...``` Gives the error ```Property 'objectContaining' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<any>'.ts(2339)```

Comment: The documentation reads:
   Matches anything but null or undefined. You can use it inside toEqual or toBeCalledWith instead of a literal value. For example, if you want to check that a mock function is called with a non-null argument: